# Make an exe which extracts multiple files

Tags: python, zip, executable

I want to make an executable file which will extract multiple files into a specific location. 
I've read about the 'extractall()' function, and using unzip, but how do I contain the multiple files inside the executable python file, so each time the user double click the exe file, it will extract these files into the hard coded location?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your archive will be (in most part) platform-specific -- it may not work on `Windows` if you make it on a `Unix-like` machine and vice versa, etc.

I would recommend that you check this `pymakeself` which is a pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymakeself

In fact, you may find the following codes immediately relevant.

**Self Extracting Archiver (Python recipe):** http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577485-self-extracting-archiver/

**Build a compressed self-extracting executable script on UNIX (Python recipe):** http://code.activestate.com/recipes/497000-build-a-compressed-self-extracting-executable-scri/